# Display tab characters as arrows of varying length

Tags: indentation, whitespace, tabs

I would like to make tab characters ("\t") display as arrows of varying length, just like in editors such as Notepad++, gedit, Geany, etc. Here is an example with tab width set to 4 and space characters displayed as dots:

[image: tab character displayed as arrow of varying length]

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality in GNU Emacs? Maybe by configuring the whitespace-mode?

Comment: The `display-table` elements take one ore more characters, which are used to represent a tab.  Thus, a stretch-glyph is not a built-in feature in so far as the `display-table` is concerned.  It is possible to create a visual effect with overlays, but that would need to be redrawn.  If we are talking the whole buffer, then it will not be efficient.  If we are talking about just the visible window, then we need a new feature that the Emacs team has toyed with and which I have implemented myself in a custom version using a new `window-start-end-hook`.  Existing mechanisms are insufficient.

Comment: To read more about this idea of knowing the bounds and targeting just the visible window (and the limitations of the existing functions `window-start` and `window-end`), there is an Emacs developer mail thread that talks about a potential new `post-redisplay-hook`.  I'm not sure if anything has happened in the past few months since I last checked.  There are a couple of bug report threads that also discuss the limitations of knowing with 100% accuracy `window-start` and `window-end` -- e.g., when scrolling, point partially visible, etc.

Comment: Another idea would be to assign a background color to the tab character itself in the `buffer-display-table` (using `make-glyph-code`) to create a stretch rectangle shade spanning the width of the tab.  It's not a visual character like an arrow, but it may be a little closer to a visual representation (beyond a plain old blank space that is).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try this:

https://github.com/twlz0ne/whitespace4r.el

Change the display mappings:

```
- (tab-mark        . [?\s ?»])
+ (tab-mark        . [?— ?⟶])
```

[image]